# Page redirection and close the window are not working in firefox

Tags: javascript

I wrote the following code to redirect the user to different pages and close the window. While the following code works fine in chrome, but it does not work in firefox.

```
function OnRequestComplete(result) {
            if (result != null) {
                window.returnValue = true;
                var myhref = '';
                myhref = result;
                window.opener.top.location.href = myhref;
                window.close();
                }
        }
```

Comment: `it does not work` - please be more specific.  What happens, what is the error?

Comment: also what version of firefox, latest?

Answer (score 0):

use this for redirection:

> ```
>         window.location.href = myhref;
> ```

If you want to close a window on firefox, use this:

> top.window.close()